# show opposite of "more like this" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to pull some logs. When I use the API to search for something (say, "where log_status=ERROR"), I get lots of results. I'd really like to show a nice smattering of entries- the opposite of "show [more like this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html)".

[Cardinality](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) gives a great aggregation of all the returned results, but it doesn't score every result.

What I'm after is slightly more complicated than a [fuzzy search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html); I want to know the uniqueness of the documents to each other, not the accuracy of their match to my query. In fact, my current `_score`s are all `1.0` because the actual query is just `*`.

It's okay if the solution is somewhat expensive (say, a `script` or `function_score` query). I just don't know how to do it.. or if this is completely out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this in ES. Sounds like you might need to cluster the documents prior to loading them into ES. Your query is just an entry point essentially, and then you want to see the pairwise similarity between the returned docs... is that correct? If so, this IS complicated, because if you use KMeans or something, you will know that certain docs are in the same cluster, but you might not get a score between them. You may consider using KMeans as a dimensionality reduction mechanism for the pairwise similarity processing.

If you don't have millions of docs, you may just be able to generate the score between docs client side working with the response from ES. If you have a ton of docs (millions) then you've got a tougher problem, and might need to use something powerful to cluster and compare prior to indexing. Also, consider getting back the docs from ES, and then doing a MLT using each doc to get more docs... then the score would be for between the docs... now I;m thinking out loud, but it depends on how much volume you have.

Comment: thanks. Knowing "that's wrong" is just as helpful as knowing there's a clear path!